# Import CSV using PowerShell: date conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, csv, import-csv

I'm importing CSV files to the MS SQL, and in different CSV files I have different date types. My code:

```
## Input Variables
$csvPath = "F:\Test\table.csv"
$csvDelimiter = ";"
$serverName = "name"
$databaseName = "dbname"
$tableSchema = "dbo"
$tableName = "dates"
$encoding = "windows-1251"



Import-Csv -Path $csvPath -encoding $encoding -Delimiter $csvDelimiter | Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance $serverName -DatabaseName $databaseName -SchemaName $tableSchema -TableName $tableName -Force
```

And, for example, dates in my CSVs are like:

```
12JAN2021:18:03:41.000000
```

The problem here is that month written by the letters

or

```
17.04.2021
```

The problem here is that SQL read this like "mm.dd.yyyy" but it's "dd.mm.yyyy"

How can I improve my code so it can automatically read date correctly and write it to my date or datetime field in the destination table?

Thanks so much!

update CSV example:

```
product;product_id;product_nm;dttm
220;text;some text;12JAN2021:18:03:41.000000
220;text;some text;1JAN2021:18:03:41.000000
564;text;some text;16JAN2021:18:03:41.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is an *"automated way"* of parsing your CSVs if they all have a different *DateTime* format. I believe you would need to inspect each file to see if the format is valid (cast `[datetime]` directly to the `string`) or if they have a format that **needs to be parsed**.

In example, both provided dates on your question, need to be parsed and can be parsed with [`[datetime]::ParseExact(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-parseexact(system-string-system-string-system-iformatprovider)):

```
[datetime]::ParseExact(
    '12JAN2021:18:03:41.000000',
    'ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss.ffffff',
    [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
).ToString('MM.dd.yyyy')

[datetime]::ParseExact(
    '17.04.2021',
    'dd.MM.yyyy',
    [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
).ToString('MM.dd.yyyy')
```

If you need help *"updating"* the `DateTime` column from your CSV you would need to provide more details on that.

---

In example, the CSV provided in the question can be updated as follows:

```sh
# Here you would use this instead:
# $csv = Import-Csv path/to/csv.csv -Delimiter ';'
$csv = @'
product;product_id;product_nm;dttm
220;text;some text;12JAN2021:18:03:41.000000
220;text;some text;1JAN2021:18:03:41.000000
564;text;some text;16JAN2021:18:03:41.000000
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

foreach($line in $csv)
{
    $line.dttm = [datetime]::ParseExact(
        $line.dttm,
        'dMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss.ffffff',
        [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
    ).ToString('MM.dd.yyyy')
}
```

Now if we inspect the CSV it would look like this:

```
PS /> $csv | Format-Table

product product_id product_nm dttm
------- ---------- ---------- ----
220     text       some text  01.12.2021
220     text       some text  01.01.2021
564     text       some text  01.16.2021
```

And all the process in pipeline would look as follows:

```
Import-Csv -Path $csvPath -Encoding $encoding -Delimiter $csvDelimiter |
ForEach-Object {
    $_.dttm = [datetime]::ParseExact(
        $_.dttm,
        'dMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss.ffffff',
        [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
    ).ToString('MM.dd.yyyy')
    $_
} | Write-SqlTableData.....
```

Comment: When I said "automated" I didn't mean that script will understand the format by it's own, I mean I can import all table using one code. It seems you gave me exactly what I was searching for, thank you!

I never used PowerShall before, so syntax is new for me. Can you gave me an example how to convert date right in my code? I mean I understand hot to convert date as you said, but how to use Import-CSF function with that? Can i use [datetime]::ParseExact(..) as method of this function or somehow? Thanks!

Comment: @Faenno sure, can you add to your question a few lines of your CSV (as plain text) so I can see the Column names and the data. It will help me showing you how to update the CSV.

Comment: I updated the question and added CSV example

Comment: @Faenno see my update hope that helps

Comment: As I understand, this code changes my csv, and then I can import it to MS SQL Server. (Am I right?)
I hoped there is the way to convert data "on the spot" during importing rows to MS SQL server.
I know python and can use pandas to do the same (rewrite CSV to prepare it for importing), but Pandas upload all CSV into RAM, and for CSVs like 25GB it's a problem.
When I use code like that, does it upload all file to the RAM to run? Is there any difference for me use Pandas or script in powershell? Thanks!

Comment: @Faenno when you do `Import-Csv` the file gets loaded as a whole in memory, I can change the code to use `ForEach-Object` instead of `foreach` but that would be slower however you could pipe it to `Write-SqlTable`. Let me know and i'll update it

Comment: No need, thank you for all your help! <3

Comment: @Faenno the last update would be more memory friendly but slower most likely. Please consider accepting the answer if the question was answered